# Connecting to Team Foundation Server with a pc with no AD

Tags: tfs, active-directory, tfs-2015, tfs-web-access

So we currently have a TFS 2015 server on premise installation.

All users are registered using Active Directory account.

PC connecting to the web portal that are using AD accounts are automatically logged in since it detects the current logged in user.

My problem is we have devices that are not in AD. E.G. personal laptops that sometimes view the portal to check work items and such.

You can type in your uname and password to log in but the problem is TFS keeps asking for the uname and password every 2 minutes or so making it tedious to do anything.

Do you have any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows, you simply add the user and password to the Credential Manager (Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Credential Manager) in the Windows Credential tab.
Make sure you use a recent version of Git for Windows which includes the proper Git credential manager.

Comment: add it in windows credential or web credential?